# Presentation of Data in Log Files

Tags: format, powershell-3.0, file-io, pscustomobject

Hi just want  to ask if it's possible that in PSCustomObject, I'll be having a duplicate array? Because I have to put a "|" but if did it twice, it won't accept unless I put a "space" on another "|" which is "| ".

```
$customtable += [PSCustomObject]@{'A'=$a; '|'=$lt1;'B'=$b;'| '=$lt2}
```

Also, is it possible that the presentation of data is like in Excel? No spaces, just one column header name then the rest would be just the value as I append the output. Currently I have this one:

http://i59.tinypic.com/f1fwo3.jpg

What I want is it will display like this one:

http://i59.tinypic.com/2959sab.jpg

No space. It will continuously log like a real-time even though it was deleted from different time.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is nice presentation, than creating custom objects (with properties like "|") is probably overkill. Instead, try to use formatting subsystem:

```
# Header...
'{0,-10}| {1,-10}| {2}' -f 'DELETED', 'MODIFIED', 'PATH'
# Vertical line...
'-' * 80

$File = Get-Item C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log

'{0,-10:yyyyMMdd}| {1,-10:yyyyMMdd}| {2}' -f (Get-Date), $File.LastWriteTime, $File.Name
```

Obviously, I only assume where "deleted" and "modified" values came from. You would use first two lines once, and last one for any file that you (?) delete. To read more about `'{0,#:format}' -f $Variable` syntax, you may want to go to [Wiki article about it](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx).